# ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement error

Tags: oracle, ora-00900

While running dbms command

```
execute dbms_utility.analyze_schema('MCC','ESTIMATE',30);
```

I got `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement` error.

Can anyone tell me what could be the reason?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Where are you calling it? SQL*Plus?

Comment: @Sandy: I have to concur with @Dougman. You've asked 18 questions and haven't accepted any of the answers you've received. This is important to some of us because it improves the answerer's reputation score. To accept an answer click on the check mark to the left of the answer - it'll change color to show which answer you've accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [execute](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12022.htm#i2697931) sentence is only for [SQL*Plus](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/toc.htm) utility.

To call a PLSQL statement from the most of applications/languages you have to try some of the following, It depends on where you are playing:

**Option 1**. Without `/`.

```
begin
  dbms_utility.analyze_schema('MCC','ESTIMATE',30);
end;
```

**Option 2**. With `/`

```
begin
  dbms_utility.analyze_schema('MCC','ESTIMATE',30);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the server output on before executing the procedure in SQL Developer. Kindly try below code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
execute dbms_utility.analyze_schema('MCC','ESTIMATE',30);
```

If you still get the same error then please open your SQL*PLUS and check if PLSQL is installed in it.

Answer (score -1):

In Oracle 10g people face ORA-0900 Invalid SQL statement. Solution is try to execute stored procedure by placing the stored procedure between `BEGIN` and `END` keywords.

```
begin
    stored_procedure_name(parameter);
end;
```